# Dependency Injection. Assign values to IENUMERABLE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
public interface IFeature
{
   string FeatureName { get; set; }
}

public interface IFeatureRegistry
{
    IEnumerable<IFeature> Features { get; set; }

    bool IsEnabled(IEnumerable<string> featurePath);
}

public interface IApplicationTenant
{
    string ApplicationName { get; }
    IFeatureRegistry EnabledFeatures { get; }
}

public abstract class AbstractApplicationTenant : IApplicationTenant
{
    public string ApplicationName { get; protected set; }
    public IFeatureRegistry EnabledFeatures { get; protected set; }
}

public class SampleTenant : AbstractApplicationTenant
{
    public SampleTenant()
    {
        ApplicationName = "Sample 1";

        EnabledFeatures = null;
    }
}
```

I am new to this field. My question is how to assign values to `EnabledFeatures`?

Thanks
Jeco

Comment: Please at least format your code.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've chosen to use private setters, your only real option is to use constructor injection which is almost identical to what you have, except you'd provide an additional overload to the SampleTenant class so it would look more like this:

```
public class SampleTenant : AbstractApplicationTenant
{
    public SampleTenant(IFeatureRegistry enabledFeatures)
    {
        ApplicationName = "Sample 1";

        EnabledFeatures = enabledFeatures;
    }
}
```

You can read more about constructor vs setter injection here: http://misko.hevery.com/2009/02/19/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection/

Answer (score 0):

Check this .Net Dependency injector out. It may help with what you need.

http://ninject.org/